# c# MyNamespace.Static.1.Designer. CS from vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, translate

I converted my programs from vb.net to C#, using ICSharpCode.
Recently, I have been trying to remove all "`using Microsoft.VisualBasic`" references to be pure C#.
I have successfully done this except in *MyNamespace.Static.1.Designer.cs*.
There are 2 references to MyGroupCollection.

```
[MyGroupCollection("System.Windows.Forms.Form", "Create__Instance__", "Dispose__Instance__", "My.MyProject.Forms")]

[MyGroupCollection("System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol", "Create__Instance__", "Dispose__Instance__", "")]
```

The errors are "

> ...MyGroupCollection could not be found..." and
> "MyGroupCollectionAttribute could not be found

".
What do I do about these?

Comment: You might not need it. Check the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.mygroupcollectionattribute?view=net-6.0

Comment: Given that the `My` namespace doesn't exist in C#, I would expect that you could just delete that and any associated files. I'd just give it a go and see what happens. Make sure your project is backed up first, of course. You ought to be using source control anyway, so you should be able to simply revert if it doesn't work.